# How to access a person's outlook calender's meeting details through rest

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, outlook, outlook-restapi

I need to access a particular person's outlook calendar's meeting details for a particular day and fetch required attendees of all his meetings on that day  so that emails can be triggered to required attendees.

I tried:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/abc@mycompany.co.in/calendarview?startDateTime=#{2019-04-15.to_s}&endDateTime=#{2019-04-23.to_s}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/abc@mycompany.co.in/calendarview?startDateTime=#%7B2019-04-15.to_s%7D&endDateTime=#%7B2019-04-23.to_s%7D)

and got the output:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token is empty.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "e015d4f6-8a46-4e4d-a0b7-f9e828088991",
      "date": "2019-04-23T11:04:08"
    }
  }
}
```

and also tried:

[https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendarview?startDateTime={2019-04-15}&endDateTime={2019-04-23}](https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendarview?startDateTime=%7B2019-04-15%7D&endDateTime=%7B2019-04-23%7D)

Both didn't work. Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need create app and grant app proper permission, then call the api with app permission(token).

You could check graph demo in github demo.

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample